# How to obfuscate parent class but keep methods for child class?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have the following classes:

```
public class Parent {
  public int mymethod1() { return 1; }
  public int mymethod2() { return 2; }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
  public int mymethod1() { return super.mymethod1(); }
  public int mymethod2() { return super.mymethod2(); }
}
```

and want to obfuscate them like this:

```
public class a {
  public int a() { return 1; }
  public int b() { return 2; }
}
public class Child extends a {
  public int mymethod1() { return super.a(); }
  public int mymethod2() { return super.b(); }
}
```

Have tried all combinations but cannot get proguard to obfuscate methods of parent but keep methods of child.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. The problem is that the child's method will no longer override the super's.
If there's a reference to a `Child` but as a `Parent` type calling `mymethod1` what should happen?
(I've barely used proguard though, so maybe it could detect such cases but I don't know.)

Comment: I tried with other method names in `Child` class but it makes no difference

Comment: Can you explain what does not work? For me the two code examples look identical!